# Why can these two functions be composed in this diagram? - CW Complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

This is taken from Rotman's Algebraic Topology:

[image]

In the red box in the image above, how are $\bar f \Phi_e$ and $\tilde G(\Phi_e \times 1)$ defined in terms of domain and codomain?

By definition, $\Phi_e : (D^n, S^{n-1}) \rightarrow (e \cup X^{n-1}, X^{n-1})$ and $\tilde f : X \rightarrow E$.  So it doesn't seem like the two functions can be composed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Phi_e$ is just the characteristic map of $e$. It goes to $X^{(n)}$ (more specifically, $e \cup X^{(n-1)}$ as he writes, but this is a subset of $X^{(n)}$ and then there is no issue with composing).

You have two functions $\alpha:A \to B$, $\beta:B' \to C$ and $B \subset B'$. The composition $\beta \circ \alpha$ is valid.

Comment: And by the same logic $\tilde G( \Phi_e \times 1) : (D^n \times I) \rightarrow (e \cup X^{n-1} \times I) \subset (X^n \times I) \rightarrow B$?

Comment: @OliverG Yes.${}$